# iOS SpriteKit how to create a node with an image from a folder within app bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to create a sprite of a random monster where my images are stored in a folder referenced within the main bundle.

```
NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString* resourceFolderPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/monsters", bundlePath];

NSArray* resourceFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resourceFolderPath  error:nil];

NSInteger randomFileIndex = arc4random() % [resourceFiles count];
NSString* randomFile = [resourceFiles objectAtIndex:randomFileIndex];

SKSpriteNode* tile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:randomFile];
```

When I run my code above, I get this error

```
SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "random_monster.png"
```

The code works if I reference the image from the main bundle. **How can I use a random image from a folder within the app bundle and pass it to SKSpriteNode?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case you can't use the `spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` method. You have to create the texture yourself from an absolute path and initialize your sprite with that texture:

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:absolutePath];
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
```

Note that doing so you will lose the performance optimizations that come with using `spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` (such as caching and better memory handling)

I recommend putting your images in the main bundle and use a specific naming scheme like this:

```
monster_001.png
monster_002.png
monster_003.png
etc...
```

Alternatively, consider using [texture atlases](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW15).

Comment: Yeah, I just found out how to do this using texture atlases: http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases

Comment: Is there any source on the spriteNodeWithImageNamed that explains exactly what other stuff it is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:] works for me using an absolute path, at least on OSX 10.9. I'm working on a project where I need to access resources outside the app bundle and it's doing the job without needing SKTexture or NSImage.

Try it :D

```
NSString *imagePath = @"~/Desktop/test.png";
SKSpriteNode *test = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[imagePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
```