# Specify the path of texture image for SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I need to get some images from my iOS app bundle's folders. However, in my case it's possible to have more than one image that have the same name. Obviously, SKSpriteNode's `initWithImageNamed:` method won't help here. Knowing the exact absolute path of each image, is there any way I can specify the path that the method should use when looking for the image? I know of the solution [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304507/ios-spritekit-how-to-create-a-node-with-an-image-from-a-folder-within-app-bundle) but it's mentioned that by applying that solution I would lose the cashing and optimizations that come with using `initWithImageNamed:` method. Is there any other way?

Note: Using of texture atlases isn't possible, since the images are big (2048px X 1536px). I got errors from Atlas Generator of exceeding the maximum dimensions when I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot multiple images with the exact same name. If you "have to have" images with the same name, then there is something wrong with your code logic.